# Cordova : Whitescreen after splashscreen

Tags: angularjs, cordova, crosswalk

I have an application on Cordova with angularJS and CrossWalk.

Smartphone is connected to a private network with a wifi, on this network no internet. So the smartphone is connected on wifi but he has no internet connection.

**Problem** : When I launch cordova Application after splash screen I have an error :

Application Error : The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

But if I launch my application with no connection on wifi, I never have my error.

I try to fix this problem by :

- wite this on config.xml : preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" /
- Create main.html that redirect on index.html

All solution doesn't work I have allways a whitescreen and after some minutes (3-5min) my application launch, but I don't have my message error.

Comment: Can you show us your code of index.html

Answer (score 0):

If the `index.html` file is present in `www` and loading properly in a web browser then you will need to inspect the app while it's running on your Android device. It's likely throwing a JavaScript error during page load that's preventing anything from being displayed. To do so, follow these steps:

- Enable developer mode debugging on your Android.
- Connect your device to your computer via USB.
- Compile the app for debug (as opposed to production) and run it on your Android device: `cordova run android --debug --target=YOURDEVICEID`
- Open up Chrome on your desktop and navigate to `chrome://inspect`

You can live inspect your app just like you would a regular web page. Hitting the refresh button will re-run the initial load and allow you to log any errors.